# R plotly - get bin sizes / breaks

Tags: r, plotly

given

```
library(plotly)
plot_ly(data = wind, x = ~r, type = "histogram")
```

how do I obtain the sizes of bins/breaks from the default algorithm? I checked the plotly object, I couldn't find the info.  It is probably rendered on the JS side?

The output should be in sense of

```
hist(wind)$breaks
```